# Semantic issue: Reference to MKMapRect is ambiguous

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I haven't found a solution in any post I checked, so I'm asking here.

I have a geolocation part in my app and when I want to add a cocoapods or a library to use clustering, this error appears in the new files:

```
"Semantic issue: Reference to MKMapRect is ambiguous"
"Semantic issue: Reference to MKMapPoint is ambiguous".
```

I've been stuck in this for hours...
Any idea what can it be??

still up! Please help :(

Comment: In 'Link Binary with Libraries' MapKit is only once..

Comment: remove mapkit and add again

Comment: This is still the same..